# Issue with nested loops and conditions in VBA

Tags: vba, loops

Thank you in advance for looking in to this!

I have an issue with a code. What I am trying to do is for the macro in Excel to compare two columns with numbers in two sheets and then based on conditions that the row will also have a string value copy the number that is missing in to the main sheet (I hope it makes sense).

```
Sub conditionalCopying()

inactiveRow = Worksheets("Inactive").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
cutRow = Worksheets("Cutting").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To inactiveRow
If Worksheets("Inactive").Cells(i, 3).Value = "North" Then

    For x = 2 To cutRow
         If Worksheets("Inactive").Cells(i, 1) <> Worksheets("Cutting").Cells(x, 1).Value Then


    Worksheets("Inactive").Rows(i).Copy
    Worksheets("Cutting").Activate

    b = Worksheets("Cutting").Cells(cutRow + 1, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Worksheets("Inactive").Activate

End If

Next i
Next x

End Sub
```

Can't include screenshots due to reputation not being high enough, sorry.

Thank you once again for your help.

Comment: What is the issue you're experiencing?

Comment: a) Your `Next i` and `Next x` are mixed up, b) You're missing an `End If` after `Next x`, and c) what issue do you have, exactly?

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response! Did not expect that. 

Macros is giving me this error: https://imgur.com/undefined

Comment: @SergejDikun Your link isn't working

Comment: ah, seems like SO is blocking the image link. It was a compiler error regarding the missing "End if". I've edited the code and it seems like it started to scan through the columns, but it's not copying the row with number "4" in it each time it finishes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe give this a try :

```
Sub conditionalCopying()

Dim Cpt As Long
inactiveRow = Worksheets("Inactive").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Cutrow = Worksheets("Cutting").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Cpt = Cutrow
For i = 2 To inactiveRow
    If Worksheets("Inactive").Cells(i, 3).Value = "North" Then

        For x = 2 To Cutrow
             If Worksheets("Inactive").Cells(i, 1) <> Worksheets("Cutting").Cells(x, 1).Value Then
                Cpt = Cpt + 1
                Worksheets("Inactive").Rows(i).Copy
                Worksheets("Cutting").Activate
                b = Worksheets("Cutting").Cells(Cpt, 1).Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
                Worksheets("Inactive").Activate

                GoTo nexti

            End If

        Next x
    End If
nexti:
Next i

End Sub
```

**Edited Code** Give this a try

```
Sub conditionalCopying()

Dim Cpt As Long
inactiveRow = Worksheets("Inactive").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Cutrow = Worksheets("Cutting").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Cpt = Cutrow
For i = 2 To inactiveRow
    If Worksheets("Inactive").Cells(i, 3).Value = "North" And Worksheets("Inactive").Cells(i, 1).Value = "11" Then

    Cpt = Cpt + 1
    Worksheets("Inactive").Rows(i).Copy
    Worksheets("Cutting").Activate
    b = Worksheets("Cutting").Cells(Cpt, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Worksheets("Inactive").Activate

    End If

Next i

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("cutting").Range("A1:D" & Cpt).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4), Header:=xlYes

End Sub
```

**Second Edit**

```
Sub conditionalCopying()

Dim Cpt As Long
inactiveRow = Worksheets("Inactive").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Cutrow = Worksheets("Cutting").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Cpt = Cutrow
For i = 2 To inactiveRow
    If Worksheets("Inactive").Cells(i, 3).Value = "North" Then

    Cpt = Cpt + 1
    Worksheets("Inactive").Rows(i).Copy
    Worksheets("Cutting").Activate
    b = Worksheets("Cutting").Cells(Cpt, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Worksheets("Inactive").Activate

    End If

Next i

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("cutting").Range("A1:D" & Cpt).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4), Header:=xlYes

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, this removed the compiler error! Now it scans through all the columns/.rows that it should, but oddly only copies one row, let me check if I can add screenshot that will look like a code: 

```
before: https://imgur.com/ExYQXMh
after: https://imgur.com/fnG9BNU
```

Comment: okay, it seems like it's copying the last row regardless of conditions

Comment: Alright, this time it copied much more but multiple times (copied both numbers that already exist and numbers that do not exists in "Cutting" tab": 

```
https://imgur.com/hVJqjbi
```

Comment: Just tried that, unfortunately it's still copying all the values multiple times just like in the previous screenshot

Comment: Sure thing:

```

The "Before" shot:
Inactive: https://imgur.com/1tidAVD
Cutting: https://imgur.com/qYh9e0k

The "After shot":
Cutting: https://imgur.com/gXJp0Ag
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean, buddy? If you mean that what should have been copied it's only one row that contains number 11 and word "North" in it. Everything else should not be copied as it exists in "Cutting" tab before I run the macro

Comment: It worked now, but if I would to add other values to "Inactive" that do not exist, then the code wouldn't work as right now it only copies the value "11". The idea is to copy all the numbers that are not in the "Cutting" sheets and that have "North" as a value in the same row.

Comment: Because that was the only value in the "Inactive" tab that should have been moved. Sorry for the confusion, buddy, I didn't understand the previous question so wasn't sure what to answer there.

Comment: Alright, seems like we're getting somewhere, it copies all the "North" values, but doesn't remove the duplicates for some reason.

Comment: It didn't, left where they were, but I've changed the code to: 

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cutting").Range("A1:D" & Cpt).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
```
and it worked. 

Dorian, thank you very much for your help, you're a life-saver!

Comment: @SergejDikun Glad I could Help You